# How did the ATRAXl have the memories of all of The Doctor's past faces and and all of the the monsters he fought?

Tags: doctor-who

In Matt Smith's first episode, *The Eleventh Hour*, he's asking the ATRAXI some questions and it pulled up the monsters he fought and all of his past incarnations.

> DOCTOR: Okay. One more. Just one. Is this world protected? Because you're not the first lot to come here. Oh, there have been so many.
>
> *(The projection shows the Daleks et al.)*
>
> DOCTOR: And what you've got to ask is, what happened to them?
>
> *(A run through of all the previous Doctors, then this Doctor steps through the projection with a jacket and bow tie.)*
>
> DOCTOR: Hello. I'm the Doctor. Basically, run.

How did the ATRAXI have the memories of the Doctor's past faces and the monsters he fought? After they scanned him they sudennly had his memories, and why did he ask Is this world protected? And what happened to them? What was the point of talking to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Atraxi didn't have the memories of all the past Doctor's incarnations after scannning him. The Doctor himself said they were monitoring the whole planet, including its own history. If you remember, they showed images of past historic events, like World War II, and in the Whoniverse, The Doctor has been a vital part of Earth's history:

> ATRAXI: Is this world important?
>
> DOCTOR: Important? What's that mean, important? Six billion people live here. Is that important? Here's a better question. Is this world a threat to the Atraxi? **Well, come on. You're monitoring the whole planet. Is this world a threat?**
>
> *(There is a projection of the world between them.)*

(Emphasis mine)

As for why he called them to come back, it was also explained in the episode. The Doctor not only wanted them to go away, but also to never come back:

> RORY: You just summoned aliens back to Earth. Actual aliens, deadly aliens, aliens of death.
>
> AMY: So this was a good idea, was it? They were leaving.
>
> DOCTOR: **Leaving is good. Never coming back is better.** Come on, then! The Doctor will see you now.

In their search for prisioner zero, the Atraxi scanned the whole Earth and its history to determine if humankind was a threat for them. It clearly wasn't, so they didn't care to burn the whole planet down in order to catch their prisioner. After delivering Prioner Zero to them, The Doctor made sure to let them know this world was under his protection, very similar to a quote used by the Tenth Doctor (David Tennant) also in his very first episode:

From *The Christmas Invasion*

> TENTH DOCTOR: By the ancient rites of combat, I forbid you to scavenge here for the rest of time. And when go you back to the stars and tell others of this planet, when you tell them of it's riches, it's people, it's potential. When you talk of the Earth, then make sure that you tell them this. **It is defended.**

It's just something The Doctor does to make sure aliens don't mess with Earth. Like he said, he has put a lot of work on it.

Comment: if The Doctor has been a vital part of Earth's history: how did the atraxi have images of all his 11 incarnations  William Hartnell, Patrick Troughton, Jon Pertwee, Tom Baker, Peter Davison, Colin Baker, Sylvester McCoy, Paul McGann,  Christopher Eccleston, and David Tennant, and all of the monsters he fought

Comment: Seriously? I'm telling you the Doctor was part of earth history, the Atraxi had images of all earth history...

Comment: @AndrewCasali All the aliens and monsters who've threatened the Earth (Daleks, Cybermen, Zygons, etc. etc.) have been stopped by the Doctor. He's the protector of the Earth. The Atraxi, knowing Earth's history, can see this one man stopping the monsters time and time again. **He's been a vital part of Earth's history, defending it for centuries.** Also, when someone goes to the trouble of answering one of your questions, it'd be nice if you could take the time to read and understand their answer rather than immediately pestering them with more questions in comments.